# Banco de Dados no Excel?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Galera, tenho uma duvida. Procurei por aí no Google e não achei nada relacionado, mas pode ter alguém que saiba. 
Tem como colocar um **Banco de Dados(MySQL)** no **Excel** ?

Queria exportar uma lista de Clientes que tenho no MySQL para uma tabela no Excel, e não sei como. Tem  como eu fazer eles se comunicarem ou eu vou ter que digitar cliente por cliente ?

Comment: Pesquise sobre o conector odbc para MySQL. Será possível extrair as informações com ele.

Comment: Uma opção seria você exportar os registros do banco de dados já para um formato que possa ser aberto no Excel. Mas você precisa ver se a ferramenta ao qual está administrando o banco de dados oferece este recurso. Geralmente o formato do arquivo é `.csv`.

Comment: Exel é **EXCEL**? Como digitou 3x da mesma forma, fiquei na dúvida. Se caso for mesmo para exportar para EXCEL, então poderá fazer o que o Carlos disse, para isso, utilize a resposta que está no SOen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253704/how-to-save-mysql-query-output-to-excel-or-txt-file?noredirect=1&lq=1 ou ainda utilizar o Power Query https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Conectar-a-um-banco-de-dados-MySQL-Power-Query-8760c647-88b9-409d-b312-6ea8f84a269b

Answer (score 0):

Certeza que não acho nada??
10 segundos que pesquisei achei isso aqui

https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/conectar-a-um-banco-de-dados-mysql-power-query-8760c647-88b9-409d-b312-6ea8f84a269b